# Understand textbox.Select()

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to understand a piece of code in order to refactor it. There are several verifications for the input value to check if they are valid, and on each verification there is a line of code that I do not understand what it does.Here is the code:

```
if (IsNotDouble(weight))
{
     MessageBox.Show("Weight must be a numeric value!");
     txtWeight.Select();
     return;
}
```

`txtWeight` is a textbox.

Can anyone tell me what `txtWeight.Select()` does here.I can not understand why this piece of code should be posted here after each time an error is thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sets the cursor into the textbox where you have to enter the weight.

Answer (score 2):

The TextBox.Select() method from MSDN.

> Activates the control. The Select method activates the control if the control's Selectable style bit is set to true in ControlStyles, it is contained in another control, and all its parent controls are both visible and enabled.

In your case, it seems whenever a validation check has failed, the particular text box is selected to activate it in order to set the visual focus to it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wt11hea.aspx):

> The Select method activates the control if the control's Selectable style bit is set to true in ControlStyles.

It means, that `Select` sets focus to the `Control` so in your scenario if `IsNotDouble(weight)` is `true`, you set focus to `txtWeight` so that user can write there a text immediately without seeking the `txtWeight` through the entire form.

Answer (score 1):

Select method activates the textbox control or you can think this as bringing the focus to the textbox.
It may not be required in your case as when the verification is happpening most probably the focus is already on that textbox